# Complex MongoDB query aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I've a document representing a house embedding many rooms. The structure is this.

```
{
   description: 'House'
   total_price: 1000,
   rooms: [{
     description: 'Small Single Room',
     type: single,
     available: true,
     price: 300
   }, {
     description: 'Big Single Room',
     type: single,
     price: 400,
     available: true
   }, {
     description: 'Another Room',
     type: single,
     price: 300,
     available: true
   }]
}
```

I'm having hard time to solve this question: how can I get all houses having available single rooms for a total price of 700.

To do this I need what follows.

- set a condition on some embedded document properties
- set a condition on the sum of the available embedded rooms
- set a condition on the sum

At the moment I'm trying to understand how this can be done. I've been looking to `aggregate` and other methods, but I couldn't find a working solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's an array. I corrected it. Bedrooms is an array of embedded documents.

Comment: The key `rooms` should be array. something like : `{ description: 'House', price: 1000, rooms: [{},{}]}`

Comment: "available single rooms for a total price of 700" -> *exactly* 700, *at least* 700 or *over* 700?

Comment: I want to find the total price < 700 when I've enough available rooms. If I've 3 available rooms but I'm searching for 2, I should be able to stop.

Comment: Can you give an example of conditions you want. I guess it should work without aggregation framework if you cache a few things, like count of rooms and total price in root document

Comment: I @rubish, I actually cached the price combinations and the free room numbers and it looks like it can work now. The query would become too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that you could use. Save remaining rooms and remaining price at root level (initialize with total price and total rooms). Whenever you set available as false for a room, subtract the price and count from remaining_price and remaining_rooms.

```
{
   description: 'House'
   total_price: 1000,
   remaining_price: 700,
   remaining_rooms: 2,
   rooms: [{
     description: 'Small Single Room',
     type: single,
     available: false,
     price: 300
   }, {
     description: 'Big Single Room',
     type: single,
     price: 400,
     available: true
   }, {
     description: 'Another Room',
     type: single,
     price: 300,
     available: true
   }]
}
```

Now you can simply query the rooms you want using (I am writing the query using mongoid, which you can convert to whatever you are using):

`House.where(:remaining_price.lte => 700, :remaining_rooms.gte => 2).to_a`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an aggregation framework answer.
Note that the first $match filters documents at the collection level
and uses $elemMatch for matching both type and availability on an array element.
In order to do the sum of the prices of the available rooms for a house,
the unavailable rooms are necessarily filtered out and lost.
Addition fields in the $group stage preserve data for viewing,
but it may be more appropriate for your app to fetch full docs via the _id's.

Hope that this answers your question in its original intent
and demonstrates the power of the aggregation framework.

test/unit/house_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

class HouseTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    House.delete_all
  end

  test "complex aggregate query" do
    puts "\nMongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
    total_price_limit = 700
    pipeline = [
        {'$match' => {'rooms' => {'$elemMatch' => {'type' => 'single', 'available' => true}}}},
        {'$unwind' => "$rooms"},
        {'$match' => {'rooms.available' => true}},
        {'$group' => {
            '_id' => '$_id',
            'description' => {'$last' => '$description'},
            'total_price_available' => {'$sum' => '$rooms.price'},
            'rooms' => {'$push' => '$rooms'},
        }
        },
        {'$match' => {'total_price_available' => {'$lte' => total_price_limit}}},
        {'$sort' => {'total_price_available' => 1}},
    ]
    docs = [
        {
            description: 'House 1',
            total_price: 1000,
            rooms: [{
                        description: 'Small Single Room',
                        type: 'single',
                        available: true,
                        price: 300
                    }, {
                        description: 'Big Single Room',
                        type: 'single',
                        price: 400,
                        available: true
                    }, {
                        description: 'Another Room',
                        type: 'single',
                        price: 300,
                        available: true
                    }]
        },
        {
            description: 'House 2',
            total_price: 600,
            rooms: [{
                        description: 'Small Single Room',
                        type: 'single',
                        available: true,
                        price: 300
                    }, {
                        description: 'Big Single Room',
                        type: 'single',
                        price: 400,
                        available: false
                    }, {
                        description: 'Another Room',
                        type: 'single',
                        price: 300,
                        available: true
                    }]
        }
    ]
    docs.each { |house| House.create(house) }
    pp House.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
  end
end
```

$ rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/1] HouseTest#test_complex_aggregate_query
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.5
Moped::VERSION:1.5.1
[{"_id"=>"5272dbe2e4d30b7e0a000002",
  "description"=>"House 2",
  "total_price_available"=>600,
  "rooms"=>
   [{"description"=>"Small Single Room",
     "type"=>"single",
     "available"=>true,
     "price"=>300},
    {"description"=>"Another Room",
     "type"=>"single",
     "price"=>300,
     "available"=>true}]}]
Finished tests in 0.046359s, 21.5708 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```